# Issue in tableview cell selection and deselection using button in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, button, multipleselection

**code:** in this code i have already selected cells ids in `selectedRows` once i reach the vc those cells are showing as selected and if i select and deselect the cells then `getting correct values in array selectedRows and getting wrong names in selectedNamesArray` why? initially when adding selected names in array then also mismatch in names indexes. where ami wrong?

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var selectedRows = [32, 38, 89, 11]
var selectedNamesArray: [String] = []

var arrayModel: [SampleModel] = [SampleModel(id: 32, name: "Apple"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 38, name: "Smasung"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 22, name: "Black berry"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 76, name: "Nokia"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 12, name: "Real me"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 75, name: "Lenova"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 36, name: "Pocco"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 11, name: "Motorola"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 37, name: "Infinix"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 88, name: "China"),
                                 SampleModel(id: 89, name: "Jio")
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    if !selectedRows.isEmpty{
        selectedNamesArray = arrayModel
            .filter { selectedRows.contains($0.id) }
            .map { $0.name }
    }
    print("existing names: \(selectedNamesArray) \n and ids: \(selectedRows)")
}
}

extension ViewController2: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    
        return arrayModel.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TestTableviewCell1", for: indexPath) as? TestTableviewCell1
    cell?.selectionStyle = .none
    cell?.titleLbl?.text = arrayModel[indexPath.row].name
    cell?.checkBtn.tag = indexPath.row
    
    cell?.isChecked = selectedRows.contains(arrayModel[indexPath.row].id)
    
    cell?.buttonAction = { [self] sender in
        
        if selectedRows.contains(arrayModel[indexPath.row].id) {
            if let indexToRemove = selectedRows.firstIndex(of: arrayModel[indexPath.row].id) {
                
                selectedRows.remove(at: indexToRemove)
                
                if indexToRemove < selectedNamesArray.count {
                    selectedNamesArray.remove(at: indexToRemove) // Remove corresponding name
                }
                //   selectedNamesArray.remove(at: indexToRemove) // Remove the corresponding name
                cell?.isChecked = false
            }
        } else {
            selectedRows.append(arrayModel[indexPath.row].id)
            selectedNamesArray.append(arrayModel[indexPath.row].name) // Add the corresponding name
            cell?.isChecked = true
        }
        print("Selected rows: \(selectedRows)")
        print("Selected names: \(selectedNamesArray)")
    }
    return cell!
}
}

class TestTableviewCell1: UITableViewCell{

@IBOutlet weak var titleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var checkBtn: UIButton!
var isChecked = false{
    didSet{
        checkBtn.backgroundColor = isChecked ? .blue : .green
    }
}
var buttonAction: ((_ sender: AnyObject) -> Void)?
@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.buttonAction?(sender)
}
}

struct SampleModel{
var id: Int
var name: String
}
```

o/p:

> existing names: ["Apple", "Smasung", "Motorola", "Jio"]
> and ids: [32, 38, 89, 11] //here also indexes are not matching with both array values

after doing some selection de selection

> Selected rows: [32, 38, 89, 36]
> Selected names: ["Apple", "Smasung", "Motorola", "Pocco"] //agin mis match in indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you filter an array, you get back an array ***in the same order*** as the original array.

So, let's simplify things a little...

```
var arrayModel: [SampleModel] = [
    SampleModel(id: 32, name: "Apple"),
    SampleModel(id: 76, name: "Nokia"),
    SampleModel(id: 11, name: "Motorola"),
    SampleModel(id: 89, name: "Jio"),
]

var selectedRows = [11, 76]

let a1 = arrayModel.filter { selectedRows.contains($0.id) }
        
print("selectedRows:")
print(selectedRows)

print()

print("Filtered:")
print(a1)
```

We get this output in the debug console:

```
selectedRows:
[11, 76]

Filtered:
[App.SampleModel(id: 76, name: "Nokia"), App.SampleModel(id: 11, name: "Motorola")]
```

Seems like it's "out of order"?

The `.filter` closure essentially says:

```
create a new, empty returnArray
```

then, loops through `arrayModel` with:

```
is element.id in selectedRows?
if yes, append element to returnArray
```

With the above code, we get:

```
32 / Apple    -- discard
76 / Nokia    -- append
11 / Motorola -- append
89 / Jim      -- discard
```

The order of the returned array doesn't care about the order of `selectedRows` ... it's just checking if `.id` is contained in `selectedRows`, so the order is:

```
["Nokia", "Motorola"]
```

If you want to do something with the "names" *in the order they were selected* you'll need to sort `selectedNamesArray` to match the order of `selectedRows`.

Or, instead of trying to maintain a `selectedNamesArray` throughout, create it when you want to do something with it, like this:

```
var selectedNamesArray: [String] = []
        
selectedRows.forEach { i in
    if let m = arrayModel.first(where: { $0.id == i }) {
        selectedNamesArray.append(m.name)
    }
}

print(selectedNamesArray)
```

outputs:

```
["Motorola", "Nokia"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code, fix the issue which you are facing, attaching screenshot for reference.. just replace this code and run :)

```
cell?.buttonAction = { [self] sender in
                
                if selectedRows.contains(arrayModel[indexPath.row].id) {
                    if let indexToRemove = selectedRows.firstIndex(of: arrayModel[indexPath.row].id) {
                        
                        let name = arrayModel[indexPath.row].name
                        if selectedNamesArray.contains(name) {
                            
                            if let indexofName = selectedNamesArray.firstIndex(of: name) {
                                selectedNamesArray.remove(at: indexofName)
                            }
                        }
                        
                        selectedRows.remove(at: indexToRemove)
                        cell?.isChecked = false
                    }
                } else {
                    selectedRows.append(arrayModel[indexPath.row].id)
                    selectedNamesArray.append(arrayModel[indexPath.row].name) // Add the corresponding name
                    cell?.isChecked = true
                }
                print("Selected rows: \(selectedRows)")
                print("Selected names: \(selectedNamesArray)")
            }
```

[image]

Thanks

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Swift did you check solution ??

Comment: Please review [answer].

Comment: @DonMag thanks for giving me instructions, actually I have fixed the main part of the code which author posted. I am very disappointed after posted my answer

Comment: While your replacement code may be an option for the OP, your answer does not contain any explanation of your new code, nor did it answer the OP's question of *"getting correct values in array selectedRows and getting wrong names in selectedNamesArray ... why?"* Also, your huge screenshots seem unnecessary...

Comment: hmm.. yes actually I just fix the problem and post it.. next time I will take care of it @DonMag